# traefik - support for remote CA-signed docker endpoints?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

We want to connect traefik to a remote docker endpoint, behind a load balancer using ssl, without authenticating the server / client with self-signed certificates:

traefik (docker client) > tcp://domain:2376 (tls) > load balancer > tcp://ip:2375 (non tls) > swarm manager (docker daemon)

Our docker daemon is not using tls.

We are getting these traefik errors because the connection happens over http:

```
level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: error during connect: Get http://load-balancer.domain:2376/v1.24/version: EOF"
level=error msg="Provider connection error Get http://load-balancer.domain:2376/v1.24/version: EOF
```

We are using these flags:

```
--api
--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80
--defaultentrypoints=http
--docker
--docker.endpoint=tcp://load-balancer.domain:2376
--docker.tls
--docker.swarmmode
--docker.domain=traefik
--docker.watch
```

We are **not** using the following flags since the endpoint is a load balancer with a trusted CA-signed certificate and we do not wish to authenticate the client:

```
--docker.tls.ca=/ssl/ca.pem \
--docker.tls.cert=/ssl/server.pem \
--docker.tls.key=/ssl/server-key.pem \
--docker.tls.insecureSkipVerify
```

The docker client, which is used by traefik, supports server authentication based on public/default CA pool by supplying the --tls flag:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#other-modes

It seems like traefik only has support for tls with client and server authentication using self-signed certificates?